# Providing setting.xml file for Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I want to provide the setting.xml file for different jobs in Jenkins, that use maven plugin.
[image]

As you can see, there is an option to use provided settings.xml file, but I can't find, where can I upload it to Jenkins.

Was trying to find it in **Manage Jenkins - Configure system**, but without any results.

Could you tell me, where can I find a way to provide

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Config file provider plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin)

This allow you to load your settings xml to the job's workspace. After this you can find it in the job settings.